# Показать скрыть div по очереди

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

не могу разобраться как по очереди закрывать и открывать блок, ниже код который только закрывает все блоки и меняет клас у span, что-бы поменять background (в моем случае на сайте нужно менять background-image, но я решил не заморачиваться и поставил просто background: цвет), а мне же нужно по очереди кликнув на 1 span.minus закрыть возле него блок .remove_block, на 2 span.minus закрыть возле него блок .remove_block,  и когда закроеться .remove_block тогда открыть блок .remove_block и поменять у span.minus на span.plus и таким же образом открывать .remove_block
Это только урывок с кода сайта, для вашей облегчения помощи
За ранее спасибо

```js
//То что я писал и у меня не получаеться
$(document). ready(function(){

$(".minus").click(function() {
  $(".minus").removeClass('minus');
  $(".minus").addClass('plus');
  
  $(".open_bl span").removeClass('minus');
  $(".open_bl span").addClass('plus');
  
  $(".remove_block").fadeOut();
});
 
  $(".plus").click(function() {
  $(".plus").removeClass('plus');
  $(".plus").addClass('minus');
  
  $(".open_bl span").removeClass('plus');
  $(".open_bl span").addClass('minus');

  $(".remove_block").fadeIn();
});
});
```

```css
.sub-inner-sidebar{
  position:relative;
}
.sub-inner-sidebar span.minus{
 background:#000;
 width:16px;
 height: 12px; 
 border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.sub-inner-sidebar span.plus{
 background:green;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-inner-sidebar">
     <div class="open_bl minus">
      <span class="minus"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="remove_block">
      1
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sub-inner-sidebar">
     <div class="open_bl minus">
      <span class="minus"></span>
     </div>
    <div class="remove_block">
     2
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sub-inner-sidebar">
     <div class="open_bl minus">
      <span class="minus"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="remove_block">
      3
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Даже в этом примере при нажатии закрываются все блоки

Comment: Вам надо через `each()`, или как вам удобней, перебирать блоки чтоб только текущий закрывался/открывался

Comment: У меня есть предложение автору: На пальцах (или хотя бы картинкой), показать, каким должен быть конечный результат. Перечитал раз 10 - увы, безуспешно...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME кошмар)) вообще не знаю как можно не понять... Вы выложили правильный ответ, а потом удалили его.. непонятно почему. Сделали вы правильно, кроме одного - не учли клик по каждому эл-ту.. Их ведь 3 одинаковых - у вас при клике на каждом срабатывал скрипт, в итоге криво работал, надо было просто добавить перед кликом `each()` и для текущего dom при клике делать изменения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.open_bl').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
      $(this).toggleClass('minus plus');
      $(this).find('span').toggleClass('minus plus');
 
      $(this).next('.remove_block').fadeToggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.sub-inner-sidebar{
  position:relative;
}
.sub-inner-sidebar span.minus{
 background:#000;
 width:16px;
 height: 12px; 
 border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.sub-inner-sidebar span.plus{
 background:green;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sub-inner-sidebar">
     <div class="open_bl minus">
      <span class="minus"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="remove_block">
      1
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sub-inner-sidebar">
     <div class="open_bl minus">
      <span class="minus"></span>
     </div>
    <div class="remove_block">
     2
    </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="sub-inner-sidebar">
     <div class="open_bl minus">
      <span class="minus"></span>
     </div>
     <div class="remove_block">
      3
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо, очень выручили